# Exporting Sharepoint online XML file to external database

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-enterprise, xml

To start, I am currently using SharePoint Online.
I want to connect to Edge Technologies.
Heres what I want to happen:
1. XML file is uploaded to a sharepoint document library on a sharepoint site
2. From the Edge software, I need to provide a "Start URL" and the XML XPath Parse expression

How do i connect an external program (in my case edge technologies) that can grab the data in the XML document.

I hope I have provided enough information.